# Destination from array on marker click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am not very experienced with javascript but I'd like to be better than where I am right now. I am terribly stuck on a project I am working on and need help badly.

I am making a map with locations that are marked from a data set exported from a file on google docs. So far I have managed to populate the markers on the map and get the infowindows set up.

I'd like the user to be able to click on a marker on the map, and then click on the Get Directions button in the infowindow to get directions from their current location (using geolocation) to the location of the marker they clicked on.

I feel like I am close (maybe that is the problem), but I don't know, and after days of trying still can't figure out, how to get the lat,lng from my array into the getDir function. Please, any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

[Here is the page](http://www.portlandstreetcarbars.com/streetcar-bars-map/) with the map on it as it is now.

Here is how I am calling and setting the data into the map -

```
function initialize() {

   var myLatlng100 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.522535,-122.659492);
   var mapOptions = {
      center: myLatlng100,
      zoom: 15,          
      mapTypeControl: true,
      zoomControl: true,
      zoomControlOptions: {
         style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
      }
   };
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

 var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();
 transitLayer.setMap(map);

 $.getJSON('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AnAPtHOSNeZvdHBpcU1NemZ5UFJaOXZDMXlBUVdnMWc/od6/public/values?alt=json',       
 function(data) {
   for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++) {
      var markerId = data.feed.entry[i].gsx$markerid.$t;
      var lat = data.feed.entry[i].gsx$lat.$t;
      var lng = data.feed.entry[i].gsx$lng.$t;
      var title = data.feed.entry[i].gsx$name.$t;
      var contentString = 
         "<div class='contentString'><h3>" + data.feed.entry[i].gsx$name.$t + "</h3><br><p>" + data.feed.entry[i].gsx$address.$t 
          + "<br>" + data.feed.entry[i].gsx$city.$t + ", "
          + data.feed.entry[i].gsx$state.$t + "</p></div>" + "<input type='button' onClick=getDir() value='Get direction here'>";          


      var markers = [markerId, lat, lng, title, contentString];
      createMarker(lat, lng, title, contentString);

   }  
 });
}
```

This is my getDir() where all the troubles are -

```
function getDir(lat,lng) {

  if (navigator.geolocation) { //Checks if browser supports geolocation          
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {  //This gets the
      var latitude = position.coords.latitude;                    //users current
      var longitude = position.coords.longitude;                 //location
      var start = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude); //Creates variable for map coordinates


    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));


    var request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
           directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
  });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the latitude and longitude into the HTML in the infowindow.  Change this:

```
  var lat = data.feed.entry[i].gsx$lat.$t;
  var lng = data.feed.entry[i].gsx$lng.$t;
  var contentString = 
     "<div class='contentString'><h3>" + data.feed.entry[i].gsx$name.$t + "</h3><br><p>" + data.feed.entry[i].gsx$address.$t 
      + "<br>" + data.feed.entry[i].gsx$city.$t + ", "
      + data.feed.entry[i].gsx$state.$t + "</p></div>" + "<input type='button' onClick=getDir() value='Get direction here'>";
```

To:

```
  var lat = data.feed.entry[i].gsx$lat.$t;
  var lng = data.feed.entry[i].gsx$lng.$t;
  var contentString = 
     "<div class='contentString'><h3>" + data.feed.entry[i].gsx$name.$t + "</h3><br><p>" + data.feed.entry[i].gsx$address.$t 
      + "<br>" + data.feed.entry[i].gsx$city.$t + ", "
      + data.feed.entry[i].gsx$state.$t + "</p></div>" + "<input type='button' onClick=getDir("+lat+","+lng+") value='Get direction here'>";
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6XF7N/1/)